# Aframe set the video player size

Tags: javascript, html5-video, aframe

I use aframe.io library to play a 360 video.  I am not able to set the aspect ratio, the height and width of the video player.

```js
   <a-scene id="scene" class="fullscreen" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
      <a-entity id="vr-camera" camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" wasd-controls-enabled="true"></a-entity>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="aframeVideo" crossorigin="anonymous" ></video>
      </a-assets>
      <a-videosphere src="#aframeVideo" rotation="0 180 0" segments-height=9 segments-width=16></a-videosphere>
    </a-scene>
```

I attempted to set the **height** and **width** via the a-scene tag and the video tag, but that doesn't work as if the setting has no effect.

Then I start hacking the code and set the height and width of a-canvas

```js
onResize() {
        console.log('window resize');
        
        const vrCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('a-canvas')[0];
        if (typeof vrCanvas !== 'undefined') {
          const vrContainerHeight = document.getElementById('vr-container').offsetHeight;
          const vrContainerWidth = document.getElementById('vr-container').offsetWidth;
          if (typeof vrContainerWidth !== 'undefined' && typeof vrContainerHeight !== 'undefined') {
           vrCanvas.style.height = vrContainerHeight + "px";
           vrCanvas.style.width = vrContainerWidth + "px";
          }
        }
```

but it distorted my video and the initial position of the play pan to the right side of my video.  So I attempted to set the aspect ration to 19:6 but changing the segments-height and segments-width which has no effect.

[image: Want to set the height and width and 16:9 aspect ratio]

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I don't know whether I should be adjusting the camera, the videosphere or the scene and changing height and width using a-canvas feels like a hack.  Thanks in advance

POST EDIT:

1. Regarding the video player pan to the right side of the footage.  I fixed it by rotation the camera rotation="0 90 0"
2. Trying to set aspect ratio with segments-height=9 segments-width=16 is definitely wrong as it skews the video (ie. a straight line looks zigzag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to set the video player size and control the aspect ratio when I "embedded" the scene and set the width and height via javascript on the scene.

```js
 onResize() {
        const aframebox = document.getElementsByClassName('aframebox')[0];
        if (typeof aframebox !== 'undefined') {
          aframebox.style.height =  myHeight;
          aframebox.style.width = myWidth; 
        }
      },
```

```html
<a-scene class="aframebox" embedded class="fullscreen" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
      <a-entity id="vr-camera" camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" wasd-controls-enabled="true"></a-entity>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="aframeVideo" crossorigin="anonymous" ></video>
      </a-assets>
      <a-videosphere src="#aframeVideo" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
    </a-scene>
```